How do I create a custom UTType with multiple extensions using Swift?
I want to create a custom UTType to support multiple extensions(cxf and rwxf)
It similar to UTType.tiff
UTType.tiff.tags
[
    public.filename-extension: ["tiff", "tif"], 
    public.mime-type: ["image/tiff"], 
    com.apple.nspboard-type: ["NeXT TIFF v4.0 pasteboard type", "NSTIFFPboardType"], 
    com.apple.ostype: ["TIFF"]
]

Currently! I can create with 1 file extension for custom UTType.
How do I create a custom UTType with multiple extensions(cxf and rwxf)?
UTType(tag: "cxf", tagClass: .filenameExtension, conformingTo: .data)


Are these new file extensions or are you supporting some existing document type? Because if they ar new then you should only use one extension for your files.

Did you add your type identifier in Info.plist? There, you can write multiple file extensions.

@Sweeper, thanks, It works

You can add as many file extensions as you want in the "Exported/Imported Type Identifiers" section of your project settings.
Here is an example where I have added "abc" and "def" as an exported type identifier:

Corresponding Info.plist code:
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Some Description</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>icon</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.example.example</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>abc</string>
                <string>def</string>
            </array>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <array/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>

You can then get this as a UTType in your code like this:
print(UTType(exportedAs: "com.example.example").tags)
// prints '[public.filename-extension: ["abc", "def"]]'

